# How to download subs with OpenSubtitlesHandler in vb net

Tags: vb.net

I wish to use  OpenSubtitlesHandler dll to download subtitles in vb2010
But I can't manage it. Can you give me exsample codes to do it.
Or another way to get it...
Please give above thing with example codes
(I am not good at working with apis)
Here I found the dll : https://github.com/vankasteelj/opensubtitles-api

```
 Dim os As MethodResponseLogIn = OpenSubtitles.LogIn("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xx")
```